# can we pass @mockbean in method praram?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

While writing test cases, I need to mock one service class only inside a method not at the top of the class. So can we mock like below ? which is not allowing, any suggestions ?

```
@Test
public void testAction(@MockBean ServiceTest serviceTest) throws Exception { 


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot. It is disallowed.

Comment: Is there a way to mock a service inside the method alone ?

Comment: Yes. Try this in your method. Mockito.mock(SomeBean.class).

Comment: I tried this but instead of mocking, which is calling the actual method as I already autowired SomeBean in the class too.                                     
 SomeBean someBean = Mockito.mock(SomeBean.class);
given(someBean.getAccountInfo(anyString(), Mockito.any(String[].class))).willReturn(someData());   Now my req is I have SomeBean to call actual method in some methods and should mock in some method. how to do this ?